What's the frequency level of 時々?
Sometimes it's translated as 'often', sometimes 'at times'. It's confusing.
How often, exactly, is 時々?

時々 should be closer to "sometimes" in English.
Questioning its frequency is a bit absurd as it is not numerical.
Try to answer this: how often is "sometimes", and how about even "often"?
Perhaps it makes more sense to compare them relatively:

never ~ 絶対にしない
occasionally ~ たまに
sometimes ~ 時々
often ~ よく
always ~ 常に

